# SelectSingleNode text()= lowercase

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I am using an xml file to build a navigation for my site and I am using classic asp to check to see which node my current page should be (so I can navigate up the xml file) using:

```
Set xmlNodes = xmlobj.selectSingleNode("//ID[../Link/text()= '" & request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO") & "']")
```

I want to convert everything to lowercase which is easy on the request.servervariable but how do I lower case the Link/text.

I have seen examples using TRANSLATE but none of these use text()= so was not sure on the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can use `translate` on the string of any node, whether it is a text node or an element values so

```
xmlobj.selectSingleNode("//*[Link[translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = '" & request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO") & "']]/ID")
```

or if you have a need to access the text node then

```
xmlobj.selectSingleNode("//*[Link[text()[translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = '" & request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO") & "']]]/ID")
```

Comment: Thanks but both of these example produce a '80004005' unknown method, any ideas

Comment: Make sure you set `xmlobj.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"` if you use MSXML 3 and want to use XPath with `selectNodes` or `selectSingleNode`. Otherwise those methods in MSXML 3 work with a different selection language.

Comment: `O` and `P` are missing in uppercase letters.